# Message Sender in Lock Screen only Saying 'Message"

Tags: sms, lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-4

Hi i have just changed over to a Galaxy S4 from an iphone5 and it is really frustrating me when i get a text message it shows on the lock screen but all it says is "Message"  and not who its from.

The 'preview message' option doesnt change it, is there any way of having this switched on?

a widget maybe?

Thanks in advance.